# Using moment.js is it possible to create a timestamp from a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, timestamp, momentjs

I want to pass to moment.js a string `10-01-2014` and to that string depending on what field it comes from have it append `00:00:00` or `23:59:59` to the passed string. Which based on the field I can append already one or the other. However moment.js is telling me "Invalid date" which I gather is my creation of the string to use.

Currently I am using jQuery UI and the date picker widget to get the initial part of the string the mm-dd-yyyy but my end goal is to pass either begining of the day midnight `00:00:00` or end of day midnight `23:59:59` and from it create a standard timestamp. I am also using timezones as well, from which I get the timezone string from else where so its not a factor per say, but just putting it in for honorable mention.

My last failed attempt was:

```
console.log(moment($beginElem.val() + ' 00:00:00').tz(timezone_str).format('X'));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a string like '10-01-2014' to momentjs, it will create a date of '0010-01-01' because it's expecting the format '2014-10-01'.

I guess you will always have to parse your input first and pass the correct format to momentjs. You can do this with:

```
var string = '10-01-2014',
    strDate = string.split('-');

// note: month is zero base index
var m = moment({
    year: strDate[2],
    month: strDate[0] - 1,
    day: strDate[1],
    hour: '00',
    minute: '00',
    seconds: '00'
});

console.log(m.format('X'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing moment.js a string, why not pass a date object instead?  Create your date object with the $beginElem.val() that you are passing to moment. And then just pass this newly created date object into moment.

Comment: For so many reasons some unknown. Doing it that was I wasn't able to consistently apply an offset to the timestamp based on the timezone and DST where applicable. It would either be plus or minus an hour for what I needed, or would assume dst was valid in regions it shouldn't have moment.js overall offers me a well rounded method of getting everything I need without having to reinvent it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
let timestamp = moment('05-01-2015 14:00', "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").unix()
```

This gives you a timestamp in unix seconds for your date based on the format you have.